# Unable to restore from WAL files

Tags: postgresql, replication, backup, write-ahead-logging

I copied both the base backup and the WAL files from my primary Postgres database to a standby database and tried to restore from them but I'm getting this error:

```
PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization

LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-02-16 19:38:58 UTC
LOG:  starting archive recovery
LOG:  restored log file "000000010000000000000001" from archive
LOG:  invalid primary checkpoint record
LOG:  restored log file "000000010000000000000001" from archive
LOG:  invalid secondary checkpoint record
PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record
LOG:  startup process (PID 26) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
LOG:  database system is shut down
```

I tried adding a checkpoint after inserting a bunch of records into a table but I'm still getting the same error.

The general flow of my script is:

```bash
# Set the postgresql.conf values (i.e.: archive_command)
...

# Set the recovery.conf values (i.e.: restore_command)
...

# Create a base backup
docker exec primary-db pg_basebackup -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/data/basebackup -Ft -z -P -X fetch

# Populate the database tables with new records
...

# Create a checkpoint
docker exec primary-db psql postgres -U postgres -c "CHECKPOINT;"

# Copy the base backup
cp -a $PRIMARY/basebackup/. $REPLICA/wal/

# Copy the WAL files
cp -a $PRIMARY/wal/. $REPLICA/wal/

# Restart the standby database to start the restoration
docker restart replica-db
```

I have the base backup and the WAL files all inside the same directory. I'm not sure if the base backup should be stored somewhere else. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You created the backup in tar format, but then you don't seem to be untarring anything.  So I think your script is not really what you show it to be.

Comment: @jjanes I looked at the contents of the tar file and it's basically just the contents of `data/` including the `postgresql.conf` and the `pg_xlog/` and all of those. Should I untar that file and replace the existing files/folders?

Comment: Perhaps you want to review this: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/warm-standby.html#STANDBY-SERVER-SETUP

Comment: You can't start up a tarred data directory.  Attempting to do so would not lead to the error you show.  So we don't what it is happening, but whatever it is is not caused by what you show.

Answer (score 0):

> I have the base backup and the WAL files all inside the same directory.

That's not correct. The WAL directory, `pg_wal`, is *inside* the data directory, the one created from the base backup.

Comment: I'm so confused.. if I want to replicate my primary to a standby using WAL files, I need to copy both the base backup and the WAL files to the standby and use the `restore_command`, no?

Comment: Yes, that's one way to do it, and how that conflicts with what I said?

Answer (score 0):

You can mount a separate disk for WAL files, but put a symlink to the mounting directory inside the directory specified in the postgres configuration file in the data_directory parameter

The best way to create a DB replica is to use the pg_basebackup command with the stream option

Here is a version of the script for starting the replica.
Note, I'm using a non-docker variant of postgresql

```
#!/bin/bash

# Stop PostgreSQL if it is running
systemctl stop postgresql

# Execute pg_basebackup to get data from the wizard
su - postgres -c "pg_basebackup -P -R -X stream -c fast -h master_db_address -U replica -D /var/lib/postgresql/data/15/main"

# We move the WAL files to a separate disk
mv /var/lib/postgresql/data/15/main/pg_wal/* /mnt/pg_wal

# Delete the pg_wal folder from the database directory
rmdir /var/lib/postgresql/data/15/main/pg_wal

# Create a symlink to the directory with WAL files
ln -s /mnt/pg_wal /var/lib/postgresql/data/15/main/pg_wal

# Change the owner and group for the pg_wal folder
chown -R postgres:postgres /mnt/pg_wal

# Start PostgreSQL
systemctl start postgresql
```

I want to remind you that this is an approximate script that will help you make a replica of the database.